Git: `stash` does not find local changes but `pull` finds them
I am trying to automate deployment of my project using Github Actions. The workflow is something like this:
    git stash
    git stash drop
    git pull
    # install dependencies and ...

When first two lines are executed, git cannot find any local change:
    out: No local changes to save
    err: No stash entries found.

But then after git pull runs, this happens:
    err: From https://github.com/*****/*****
    err:  * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
    err:  ****..****          main       -> origin/main
    err: error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    err:    thefile
    err: Please move or remove them before you merge.
    err: Aborting

Why is it happening?

Notice how the error message talks about untracked files. git stash handles untracked files only when you ask it to do so, but you do not. For this reason, git stash does nothing.

If you don't think you'll gain any benefit from stashing the files first, then consider just cleaning them instead.

@TTT wow I have been working with git for more than 4 years and I haven't heard of git clean even once! Thank you my friend. Learned something new :)

Your changes are untracked. By default, git stash includes only tracked files.
If you want the changes to be stashed, you need either of the following:

modify command to include untracked files: git stash --include-untracked
make files tracked using git-add, e.g. to track all files: git add *


Oh, my bad. It was a dumb mistake; I don't know if I should delete my question or not BTW Thank you

@NavidNaseri Everybody does mistakes like this :) Don't delete it, it may help others.
